# How to trigger dialog in Microsoft Azure botbuilder?

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

This is my code:

```
.matches('Job roles', (session) => {


lib.dialog('/HowAreYou', [
    (session, args, next) => {
        session.send('I\'m doing well. Thanks for asking!');
        builder.Prompts.text(session, 'How are you doing today?');
    }, (session, results) => {
        session.endDialog('Good to hear that!');
    }
]).triggerAction({
    matches: /^how are you?$/i,
    onSelectAction: (session, args, next) => {
        // Add the help dialog to the top of the dialog stack (override the    
        // default behavior of replacing the stack)
        session.beginDialog(args.action, args);
    }
});


})
```

As you can see, I want:

1. To recognize the intent of the user **(it works)**
2. To start a
   dialog after recognizing the intent of the user **(does not work)**

How can I trigger the above dialog when I know the intent of the user? What am I missing here?

Whenever I try to test it, it says this:

```
Oops. Something went wrong and we need to start over.
```

Comment: What is the trace log/error the bot is throwing?